# Iterating changes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In the HTML below, I would like to copy the "submittedby" beside "message", within the H2 tag:

```
<div class="comment">
<H2 class="threadtitle">Message 1</h2>
<span class="submittedby">James</a>
</div>

<div class="comment">
<H2 class="threadtitle">Message 2</h2>
<span class="submittedby">Bill</a>
</div>

<div class="comment">
<H2 class="threadtitle">Message 3</h2>
<div class="submittedby">Phil</a>
</div>
```

My current jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.submittedby').copy().appendTo('.threadtitle');
});
```

The problem is this copies EVERY "submittedby" to EVERY "threadtitle". How do I code it so it only copies the "submittedby" from within the same "comment" div?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) here, like this:

```
$(function(){ 
  $('.submittedby').each(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo($(this).siblings('.threadtitle'));
  });
});
```

This loops over each `.submittedby` element, and moved it around with respect to the **current** `.submittedby` you're on in the loop, so each one's handled individually.  Also I assumed you meant [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) here, but if you're actually using the [`.copy()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/659), just replace `.clone()` with `.copy()` in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.submittedBy'.each(function() {
  var $sb = $(this);
  $sb.copy().appendTo($sb.closest('.comment').find('h2.threadtitle'));
});
```

When you use `.each()` you get to have code run for each element processed.

**edit** thanks @Nick

Comment: Oh you'[re right; sorry, I misread it. (I guess it'd make no sense if it already were a child!)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.submittedby').each(function() {
    $(this).prev('.threadtitle').append($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('span.submittedby, div.submittedby').each(function() { 
        self = $(this);
        self.before(self.clone());
    });
});
```

**[Obligatory example](http://jsbin.com/exuzi/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to limit by parent:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.submittedby:parent').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.submittedby').copy().appendTo('.threadtitle');
    })
});
```